# Angular 8 Child Routes not working from component

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, angular-routerlink, ngx-admin

I have a strange issue, I've cloned ngx-admin and trying to use the theme as base theme.

I've created `Layout Components` with `Modules` with `Routing` enabled. Created routes and connected components but the problem is routes are working fine if I open them from link directly. But when I try to use `router.navigate` to redirect, the routes are not working.

below are my files

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { DashboardLayoutComponent } from './layouts/dashboard-layout/dashboard-layout.component';
import { AuthenticationLayoutComponent } from './layouts/authentication-layout/authentication-layout.component';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'app',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'app',
        loadChildren: () => import('./layouts/dashboard-layout/dashboard-layout.module').then(m => m.DashboardLayoutModule)
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticationLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'auth',
        loadChildren: () => import('./layouts/authentication-layout/authentication-layout.module').then(m => m.AuthenticationLayoutModule)
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'app'
  }
];

export const AppRoutingModule : Routes = routes;
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardLayoutComponent,
    AuthenticationLayoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutingModule),
    CookieModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
    NbMenuModule.forRoot(),
    NbWindowModule.forRoot(),
    NbToastrModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**auth-layout.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from '../../pages/auth/login/login.component';
import { ForgotComponent } from '../../pages/auth/forgot/forgot.component';
import { VerifyComponent } from '../../pages/auth/verify/verify.component';

export const AuthenticationLayoutRoutingModule : Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'forgot', component: ForgotComponent },
  { path: 'verify/invite/:_hash', component: VerifyComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
]
```

**auth-layout.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    ForgotComponent,
    VerifyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(AuthenticationLayoutRoutingModule),
    ThemeModule,
    NbAlertModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NbPopoverModule,
    NbCardModule,
    NbIconModule
  ],
})
export class AuthenticationLayoutModule { }
```

Im trying to navigate from Verify component to login component, Below is the code

```
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private authService: AuthService, private toastrService: NbToastrService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate['/auth/login'];
  }
```

But if I use below code, It will redirect properly

```
<a [routerLink]="['/auth/login']">Click to redirect</a>
```

Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Is `this.router.navigate['/auth/login'];` a typo, or your actual code?

Comment: Sorry.This is stupid. I missed parenthesis. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `router.navigate` correctly. It is a function, and should be called like one:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
}
```

#### Router module patterns

In an unrelated issue, your routing modules are declared in a confusing way. What you're naming as modules aren't really modules.

The typical patterns would either be:

app.module.ts

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  // ... routes here
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**OR**

app-routing.module.ts

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  // ... routes here
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  export: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Sticking to common conventions helps when it comes to reading new code (or your own old code) - you can recognise common patterns without having to mentally parse unfamiliar ones.